# netlogo: problem with array: from-list (filter

Tags: arrays, filter, netlogo

I want to filter item 1 from my data set. the original data set is a txt file and like:
 [ [1 "firm" [23 34] [1] "Tehran" "SME" 1389 "Applied Research" 70 6 "Nanotech" 28571]
8 "lab" [14 27] [1 6] "Tehran" "Public " 1386 "Basic Research" 71 65 "Biotech" 502974] ]
the main code for analyzing data is:

```
extensions [ array matrix table ] 
globals [
initial-emperical-data
emperical-firm-agent-records
  emperical-lab-agent-records ]
to setup
setup-agents
end
to setup-agents
load-initial-empirical-data
analyze-initial-empirical-data
end

to load-initial-emperical-data
 set activity "loading initial emperical data"
  if (file-exists? "c://users//saeed//desktop//initialempericaldata.txt")
 [ file-open "c://users//saeed//desktop//initialempericaldata.txt"
   set initial-emperical-data file-read
file-close ]
to analyze-initial-empirical-data 
set activity "Analyzing initial empirical data"
set activity "Analyzing initial empirical data"
set emperical-firm-agent-records (array:from-list (filter [? -> is-firm-record? ?] initial-emperical-data ))
set emperical-lab-agent-records ( array:from-list (filter [? -> is-lab-record? ?] initial-emperical-data ))
end
to-report is-firm-record? [rec]
report (org-type-for-agent-record rec ) = "firm"
end   
to-report is-lab-record? [rec]
  report (org-type-for-agent-record rec ) = "lab"
end
to-report org-id-for-agent-record [rec]
  report item 0 rec
end 
to-report org-type-for-agent-record [rec]
  report item 1 rec
end
```

when i want to run the model i get this error: FILTER expected input to be a list but got the number 0 instead.
how can i fix this error? 
thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

1. Please include a minimal working example (MWE) with your code.
2. It seems you forgot to initialize your globals.

The following works fine:

```
extensions [array]
globals [initial-empirical-data empirical-firm-agent-records empirical-lab-agent-records activity]

to test
  setup
  analyze-initial-empirical-data
end

to setup
  set initial-empirical-data [ 
    [1 "firm" [23 34] [1] "Tehran" "SME" 1389 "Applied Research" 70 6 "Nanotech" 28571] 
    [8 "lab" [14 27] [1 6] "Tehran" "Public " 1386 "Basic Research" 71 65 "Biotech" 502974]
  ]
end

; the main code for analyzing data is:

to analyze-initial-empirical-data 
set activity "Analyzing initial empirical data"
set activity "Analyzing initial empirical data"
set empirical-firm-agent-records (array:from-list (filter is-firm-record? initial-empirical-data ))
set empirical-lab-agent-records ( array:from-list (filter is-lab-record? initial-empirical-data ))
end

to-report is-firm-record? [rec]
report (org-type-for-agent-record rec ) = "firm"
end   
to-report is-lab-record? [rec]
  report (org-type-for-agent-record rec ) = "lab"
end
to-report org-id-for-agent-record [rec]
  report item 0 rec
end 
to-report org-type-for-agent-record [rec]
  report item 1 rec
end
```